# Auto primary key insert custom table $wpdb

Tags: php, mysql

I need to insert to custom table that has primary key 'id' by number, but I got this problem for example

I have 5605 rows (start with id = 1) in my table,so I have to set current id = 5606 to insert.

1/I set $data['id'] = 5606 by hand to insert it, it works fine. current row with id 5606 is inserted.

but I want it automatically get the right id to insert so I do

2/select * to returns the current number of rows in table, it returns 5604 (always lesser by 1 when I check database has 5605). so I + 2 then do insert.
It ends up insert 3 times like 5606 5607 5608 in my table.
Please help me here is my code

```
 $data = array(
  'name' => 'naomi',
  'ability'  => 'walk',
 );

 $wpdb->get_results("SELECT *  FROM contest");
 $numid = $wpdb->num_rows; 
 $numid +=2;
 $data['id'] = $numid;
 $wpdb->insert('contest', $data);
```

The given number is for example, my problem is in that format.

Comment: You are looking for [`AUTO_INCREMENT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html). It's the standard way to go for this kind of scenario - updating the number in code has concurrency problems. The auto increment solves all of those.

Comment: Hi , when I dont set id for the new row, it only works 1 time inserted the current row with id = 0 then it doesnt work any more. but I have 5605 rows start by id = 1, I'm very beginner please suggest me a bit more?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just declare column id (or whatever you use as primary key) as [`AUTO_INCREMENT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html) (in MySQL) or SERIAL (in PostgreSQL) and insert all other columns but your primary key.
Example:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255),
PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

INSERT INTO persons (LastName,FirstName,Address,City) VALUES (
'Sample','Person','Sample-street','Sample-city'
);
```

More than! You should not use any manual inserts for primary keys, because it can make you a lot of problems with handling unsuccessfull queries etc.

**SECOND PART.** To return number of rows in your table just use

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM persons;
```

Comment: Added manual link to mySQL's `AUTO_INCREMENT`. Adding manual links when introducing concepts is not strictly required, but a good practice and (if that's important to you) a good way to get more upvotes!